# Why are these symbols and numbers in my ID?

Tags: discussion, flair, numbers, symbols

I don't care about my reputation, but I have some confusion about symbols in my Stack Exchange ID (shown below)

[image]

I don't understand the meaning of these symbols and numbers.

Why are these symbols and numbers in my ID?

Comment: That are your gold, silver and bronze badges

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for

Comment: That is explained in the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Also in hover text, although if one doesn't know what "badges" are, the hover text won't help.

Comment: The gold one means you will live a life filled with happiness and joy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This represents your *flair* and denotes the number of gold, silver and bronze badges you've received on that specific site (or across all sites if you view your network profile). Specific to your example, you have

- 1 gold badge
- 12 silver badges
- 34 bronze badges

on [Mathematics.SE](//math.stackexchange.com); that site uses geometric shapes for badge icons.

Visualizations of the respective badges differ across sites, since they may have a local design element that has been created. For example, [Academia.SE](//academia.stackexchange.com) uses graduation caps for their badges

[image]

while [Geographic Information Systems.SE](//gis.stackexchange.com) and [Travel.SE](//travel.stackexchange.com/) uses map points for badge icons

[image]

Comment: Perhaps explain what *flair* refers to. The term "flair" in this context is likely a reference to the film *[Office Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Space)*, in three scenes, at about 24 min 50 secs, [30 min 45 secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ChQK8j6so8&list=RD_ChQK8j6so8), and [53 min 17 secs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7SNEdjftno).